# aws 2.0 > step function > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/core/runtime/transform/Unmarshaller

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, java-11, aws-step-functions

Getting this below error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/core/runtime/transform/Unmarshaller
```

When executing the below code,

```
@Test
public void testStateFunction() {

    SfnClient sfnClient = SfnClient.create();
    System.out.println(sfnClient);

}
```

Have the below dependencies defined in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.17.29')

//    implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 'core', version: '2.17.29', ext: 'pom'
        implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:core:2.17.29'
//    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.17.29'
//    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.17.29'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:stepfunctions:2.0.0-preview-11'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.10.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.2.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.0'
    runtimeOnly 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j18-impl:2.13.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

Tried many online searches, can't fix it yet.

From the InteliJ left menu Gradle libraries, when I try to expand
sdk-core, cannot find the class software/amazon/awssdk/core/runtime/transform/Unmarshaller in any jars.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation found out that

The right latest dependency is

```
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sfn:2.17.29'
```

And seems the below one which I tried initially was outdated and hence it did not worked with AWS 2.0 core jar /Unmarshaller which does not exist.

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2094
Thanks

```
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:stepfunctions:2.0.0-preview-11'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use AWS Step Functions using the AWS SDK for Java V2. To get this use working, you can follow this AWS end to end example that walks you through this use case and you will create the following workflow using AWS Step Functions.

[image]

Follow this document:

[Create AWS serverless workflows by using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_workflows_stepfunctions)

It uses Maven - but shows you the required dependencies (Once you get it working with Maven, then port the dependencies to gradle).